# Multiple selection problem in a list box

Tags: html

Is there any way through which we can get all the selected values in a list box?

Comment: belongs on SO... could someone migrate?

Comment: Agreed. Definitely a developer question.

Comment: Perhaps author can delete it from here and post on SO

Answer (score 2):

do you mean

```
<select name="foo" MULTIPLE>       
  <option value="bar1" >Option 1</option> 
  <option value="bar2" >Option 2</option> 
  <option value="bar3" >Option 3</option> 
</select>
```

so that the end user can select multiple items in a form?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can give the select an array-style name:

```
<select name="items[]" multiple>
  <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Accessing these values from the server-side is rather simple:

```
<?php

  foreach ($_POST["items"] as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br/>";
  }

?>
```